# How to remove these strange white space on the sides?

Tags: css

I'm developing web music player. I want to make blurred background for my album covers, and I got these annoying white spaces around the edges. I think that the problem is in algorithm that tries to smoothly upscale an image and gets around 0.5px of white space. But I don't know how to remove that.

```css
.bg-img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    filter: blur(5px) brightness(0.4) saturate(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img"><div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found two solutions:

1. add solid black shadow around your image: `box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px black`
2. force image to overflow on all sides (`inset: -10px` is equal to setting top, bottom,left and right to -10px)

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bg-img {
  position: absolute;
  inset: -10px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  filter: blur(5px) brightness(0.4) saturate(2);
}
```

```html
        <div class="bg-img"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the blur. When you blur an image, it's reducing the density of that image around the blur radius. What you're seeing is the white background of the site. Unless you need the body for anything particular, you can change the background color on that to something to mask it (black, white, blue, whatever)

Black actually works kind of nicely as a vignette effect if you're into that

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.bg-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Dl59c15XsAAf6a7?format=jpg&name=240x240");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(5px) brightness(0.4) saturate(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Backdrop Filter

What [AStombaugh says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72673297) is right.

However, to achieve what you are looking for you can create the blur in another way.

Try this:

```css
.bg-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.blur {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px) brightness(0.4) saturate(2);
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img">
  <div class="blur"></div>
</div>
```